# Adding custom footnote using pages 5.1

Tags: applescript

I would like to change the footnote sign from numbers to characters in Pages 5.1.

I could not find any information on this on the internet. I tried ctrl+click and option+click when inserting the footnote but the custom footnote option seems to be gone from this version.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If your cursor is clicked into the text of the footnote (i.e. you are editing `1:  Jane Smith, "My Book" (New York: Columbia UP, 2014`, not `Which scholars have described as "such and such."^1`), a "Footnotes" section will appear in the "Format" sidebar (it will show up next to "Text," which  is normally the only section) where you can choose from among a few styles. I think this will solve your problem.

That said, this is exceptionally clunky and counter-intuitive.

Also, if you want to mix styles (e.g. have a first note under `*` and subsequent notes under `1`, `2`, `3`, …), there doesn't seem to be a way to do that, though vexingly it looks like one may have existed in earlier versions of Pages.